# How can I extract a meaningful directed acyclic graph of the dependencies in Google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

At it's core a spreadsheet is a DAG of functions (nodes) and dependencies (edges)  How can I extract that data structure from a google sheet?

I have some dependency that is slowing the results of certain lookups, and am hoping that the dependency tree will give me a clue what's wrong.

Comment: Can you provide more details about what kind of data structure you're looking for?

Answer (score 0):

One way to track dependencies is to **File > Download > OpenDocument format**, open the file in OpenOffice, and use **Tools > Detective**.

Note that it is unlikely that dependencies would be the root cause of the slowness you mention. See these [these spreadsheet optimization tips](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/102271339?msgid=102278707).